# Смена jdk на 11 версию

Tags: java

Подскажите, после установки jdk-11.0.1 в IntelliJ IDEA при попытке скомпилировать программу стало выдавать такую ошибку:

> Information:javac 8 was used to compile java sources
>   Information:Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format,
>   forcing project rebuild: Module 'voina' production:
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jrt
>   Information:27.10.2018 14:27 - Compilation completed with 1 error and
>   3 warnings in 39s 564ms Error:Internal error:
>   (java.net.MalformedURLException) unknown protocol: jrt
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jrt     at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:421)     at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:310)     at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:333)     at
>   com.intellij.compiler.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassFinder.createJDKPlatformUrl(InstrumentationClassFinder.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.instrumentation.ClassProcessingBuilder.createInstrumentationClassFinder(ClassProcessingBuilder.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.instrumentation.ClassProcessingBuilder.build(ClassProcessingBuilder.java:93)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1246)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:923)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:995)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:886)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:719)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:371)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Please perform full project
>   rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project) Warning:java: source value 1.3 is
>   obsolete and will be removed in a future release Warning:java: target
>   value 1.3 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   Warning:java: To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use
>   -Xlint:-options.

Подскажите в чем дело?

Comment: Смените вкрсию компилятора в настройках иде с 1.8 на 11

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить?

Comment: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler

Comment: В выборке нет 11, последняя 9, но выдает ошибку.